# One function to accept void func(void) and void func(void* param)

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am using C with the GNU compiler collection.
So I need to pass function pointers to a function. Now there are two types of acceptable function pointers prototypes that I want to handle:

```
void function(void);
```

and

```
void function(void* param);
```

Right now I have the follwing:

```
int createProcess(void (*procFunc)(void*), void* param);
```

This will only work for the second prototype. Is there a way to make it work for both the example prototypes?

Comment: How would you intend to distinguish between the two kinds of function pointers once you received them? C doesn't have function overloading of any kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function pointer with an unspecified number of parameters:

```
int createProcess(void (*procFunc)(), void* param);
```

but then you also need to distinguish the two kind of function. Either add a third parameter or (if your function don't already use it) use a null pointer value for `param` as a flag to distinguish the two kind of functions.

Note that declaration of functions with an unspecified number of parameters is an obsolescent C feature, so you may consider declaring two different `createProcess` functions.

Comment: This solution makes is the same as createProcess(void (*procFunc)(void), and thus will not accept functions with a param. I do not need to distinguishthe two kinds of function, I really only need to pointer and I would like to do it without a typecast on the senders' side.

Comment: @Cheiron `void (*procFunc)()` is not the same as `void (*procFunc)(void)`

Comment: yes I should have updated the header file. You were right, many thanks.

Comment: Two separate functions is my prefered solution; with the `()` version you lose the ability for the compiler to check prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a type something like this.

```
typedef struct fnn {
  int fntype;
  union {
    void (*fn0)(void);
    void (*fn1)(void* param);
  } fn;
} fnArg;
```

Put 0 or 1 in the fntype to identify which of the union fields you've used, populate the relevant fn.fn0 or fn.fn1 and pass this structure as the first argument.

This is basically what a more complex language would do, but it would hide the details.

EDIT: You can also use just the union if you have some other way of deciding which of the fields is in use.